# How to find degenerate rows/columns in a covariance matrix

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, singular

I am using numpy.cov to create a covariance matrix from a dataset of over 400 time series. Using linalg.det gives me a value of zero so matrix is singular. I can use linalg.svd to see that the rank is two less than the number of columns so somewhere in the covariance matrix I have some linear combinations to make the matrix degenerate. I have used corrcoef on the underlying timeseries but no correlation > 0.78 so not obvious there. Can someone suggest a method to determine the location of the degenerate columns. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

If you take the `QR` decomposition of a matrix `A`, the columns of `R` with a non-zero value along the diagonal correspond to linearly independent columns of `A`.

---

```
import numpy as np
linalg = np.linalg

def independent_columns(A, tol = 1e-05):
    """
    Return an array composed of independent columns of A.

    Note the answer may not be unique; this function returns one of many
    possible answers.

    http://stackoverflow.com/q/13312498/190597 (user1812712)
    http://math.stackexchange.com/a/199132/1140 (Gerry Myerson)
    http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2008-November/038705.html
        (Anne Archibald)

    >>> A = np.array([(2,4,1,3),(-1,-2,1,0),(0,0,2,2),(3,6,2,5)])
    >>> independent_columns(A)
    np.array([[1, 4],
              [2, 5],
              [3, 6]])
    """
    Q, R = linalg.qr(A)
    independent = np.where(np.abs(R.diagonal()) > tol)[0]
    return A[:, independent]

def matrixrank(A,tol=1e-8):
    """
    http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2008-February/031218.html
    """
    s = linalg.svd(A,compute_uv=0)
    return sum( np.where( s>tol, 1, 0 ) )


matrices = [
    np.array([(2,4,1,3),(-1,-2,1,0),(0,0,2,2),(3,6,2,5)]),
    np.array([(1,2,3),(2,4,6),(4,5,6)]).T,
    np.array([(1,2,3,1),(2,4,6,2),(4,5,6,3)]).T,
    np.array([(1,2,3,1),(2,4,6,3),(4,5,6,3)]).T,
    np.array([(1,2,3),(2,4,6),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)]).T
    ]

for A in matrices:
    B = independent_columns(A)
    assert matrixrank(A) == matrixrank(B) == B.shape[-1]
```

`assert matrixrank(A) == matrixrank(B)` checks that the `independent_columns` function returns a matrix of the same rank as `A`.

`assert matrixrank(B) == B.shape[-1]` checks that the rank of `B` equals the number of columns of `B`.

Comment: Say I have already reduced the matrix to its independent matrix, which has a full rank(for the columns) - then if I run an LR model on it and still get the error, I assume the tolerance should be way more higher. But then, YOUR code actually BUILDS on top of linalg , should I increase the tolerance in the "independent_columns" above ? what's the default tol in in linalg.py ? Error log while doing Logit (Statsmodels) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 328, in solve
    raise LinAlgError, 'Singular matrix'
LinAlgError: Singular matrix

Comment: Just to add, I read through the linalg.py file, but couldn't pin-point on the "tol" it is feeding on. This is the file (To save you lookup time, in case you consider answering ) https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/linalg/linalg.py . Have also recorded the whole scenario(Don't think its an issue though) in git here, https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4715

Comment: I'm not sure I'd be able to help you, but could you post code which demonstrates the problem? Especially since code does not format well in comments, please start a new question for this.

Comment: After trying hard to debug the issue, I posted the issue here. Please see if you can take a stab at it ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23848003/detecting-mulicollinear-or-columns-that-have-linear-combinations-while-modelli