# QR decomposition for rectangular matrices in which n > m in scipy/numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, qr-decomposition

I have a m x n rectangular matrix A for which n > m. Given the rank r <= m of A, the reduced QR decomposition yields matrix Q with m x r dimensions, and R with r x n dimensions. The columns of Q are an orthonormal basis for the range of A. R will be upper triangular but in a staircase pattern. Columns in R with a pivot correspond to independent columns in A.

When I apply qr function from numpy.linalg (there is also a version of this function in scipy.linalg, which seems to be the same), it returns matrix Q with m x m dimensions, and R with m x n dimensions, even when the rank of matrix A is less than m. This seems to be the "full" QR decomposition, for which the columns of Q are an orthonormal basis for Re^m. Is it possible to identify the independent columns of A through this R matrix returned by function qr in numpy.linalg;scipy.linalg?

Answer (score 2):

Check for diagonal elements of R that are non-zero:

```
import numpy as np
min_tol = 1e-9
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,3,2],[1,1,1]])
print("Matrix rank of: {}".format(np.linalg.matrix_rank(A)))
Q,R = np.linalg.qr(A)
indep = np.where(np.abs(R.diagonal()) >  min_tol)[0]
print(A[:, indep])
print("Independent columns are: {}".format(indep))
```

see also here:
[How to find degenerate rows/columns in a covariance matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13312498/how-to-find-degenerate-rows-columns-in-a-covariance-matrix)