# logistic regression using statsmodels error in python

Tags: python, matrix, logistic-regression, summary, matrix-inverse

I am trying to implement a logistic regression using statsmodels (I need the summary) and I get this error:

```
LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

My df is numeric and correlated, I deleted the non-numeric and constant features.
I tried to implement regular regression as well as one with l1 penalty (l2 isn't available) because of the correlated features.

I tried to check the matrix rank and got this print:

```
print(len(df.columns)) -> 156

print(np.linalg.matrix_rank(df.values)) -> 151
```

How do I know which features are a problem and why?

my code:

```
logit = sm.Logit(y,X)

result = logit.fit_regularized(trim_mode='auto', alpha=0,maxiter=150)

print(result.summary())
```

Update:

after removing highly correlated features I get:

```
  len(df.columns) =  np.linalg.matrix_rank(df.values)
```

but still the same error. (even if I set a low correlation threshold).

I tried to change the solver as well.

Comment: Try df.corr() - this returns a matrix of correlations between the numeric columns in your dataframe. From that you can check if any two of your features are exactly correlated.

Comment: @Johannes Wachs , I deleted the correlated features and it works. tnx.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13313828/333700 for how to use QR to find all collinear or linearly independent columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, if two features are exactly correlated the model won't run. The easiest way to check this if you have a pandas dataframe with a small number of columns is to call the [.corr() method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) on your dataframe - in this case df.corr(), and check if any pair of features have correlation =1.

You should really think about why some features are perfectly correlated though.

Comment: is there any other reason way? I just removed all of the features with 0.4 corr and up and I got the same error...